# How can I get a bower list without the betas?

Tags: bower

When I run `bower list` it include betas in the list which isn't helpful if I'm trying to stay on stable. Like this:

```
├─┬ ember#1.13.4 (latest is 2.0.0-beta.2)
│ └── jquery#1.11.3 (2.1.4 available, latest is 3.0.0-alpha1+compat)
├─┬ ember-cli-shims#0.0.3
│ └── ember#1.13.4 (latest is 2.0.0-beta.2)
├── ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3
├─┬ ember-data#1.13.5
│ └── ember#1.13.4 (latest is 2.0.0-beta.2)
├─┬ ember-load-initializers#0.1.5
│ └── ember#1.13.4
├── ember-qunit#0.4.1
├─┬ ember-qunit-notifications#0.0.7
│ └── qunit-notifications#0.0.6
├─┬ ember-resolver#0.1.18
│ └── ember#1.13.4 (2.0.0-beta.2 available)
├── jquery#1.11.3 (latest is 3.0.0-alpha1+compat)
├── loader.js#3.2.1
└── qunit#1.18.0
```

Is there a convenient way of excluding betas from the list?

Comment: its just telling you about newest version whats problem ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I have no way of knowing if there's a new stable version. For instance. *jquery#1.11.3 (latest is 3.0.0-alpha1+compat)*. There's jQuery 2.1.4 available, I have no way of knowing that. If I had Ember *1.13.3* it would say latest is *2.0.0-beta.2* rather than *1.13.4*.